# Double click on cell and find value another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search the web for VBA code that could help me, but I couldn't find anything.

What I trying to do:

- In the same workbook, I have two sheets.
- In sheet 1, a column A with lots values (numbers only).
- In sheet 2, a column A with these values (sometimes more than 1 time the same value) with many more information in other columns.

So far, okay.

What I need is, when I double click in one of these values from sheet 1, excel shows only the same values in sheet 2 (not only the first occurrence), hiding the others.

Example:

```
Sheet 1
Column A
123
124
125
126

Sheet 2
Column A
123
124
123
125
123
126
```

When clicking in cell with value 123 from sheet 1, excel shows the lines with the same value only in sheet 2, hiding the other values.

I don't know how to code. However, this code I think, can be used. The only problem. It is returning the line number of the first occurrence in a pop up box. What I need is, Excel shows in the sheet the values founded.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'If you select more than one cell, ignore
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

'If you select a blank cell, ignore
If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Dim Finder, ClickRange

'We want the event to fire if you click in column A anywhere
Set ClickRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

'If you click somewhere else, ignore
If Intersect(Target, ClickRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Look for the value in sheet 2 column A
Set Finder = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

'If we don't find it, Exit Sub
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'To display the row:
MsgBox (Finder.Row)

'To Select it:
'If we find it, select sheet 2 and select the cell
'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Finder.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54132332/edit) to give us sample data, expected outcome, what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better experience if you
take moment to take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can
also read about asking a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an
attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: First of all there is no double click event for worksheets. You will eg need to select a value and click a button for this. Secondly you can read the value with `Selection.Value` and then perform a `AutoFiter` with that value on your sheet2. If you search here or Google you will find many tutorials how to use AutoFilter in VBA. Give it a try and come back with your code attempt telling where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: There's going to be no canned code for you to copy and paste and make this work. You will have to write the code. If you get stuck with a specific issue, feel free to head back and ask about that specific issue. Right now this question reads like "Write my code for me, here's my spec" which is too broad for a Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) to filter the data in sheet 2 by the selected value in sheet 1.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterBySelectedValue()
    Dim wsFilter As Worksheet
    Set wsFilter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    wsFilter.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Selection.Value
    wsFilter.Activate 'switch to filtered sheet
End Sub
```

Just select a value in sheet 1 and then run the macro by button or keyboard shortcut. I highly recommend not to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, otherwise your sheet 1 will easily become unusable.

So with the following selected value in sheet 1 …

[image]

… after running the procedure the result of sheet 2 will show:

[image]